# Eclipse plugin samples

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm pretty new to the Eclipse IDE and I need to develop a paint plugin. I read that there is one in the plugin sdk, but it's not clear to me how to create a project which uses that.

I installed the plugin sdk as described here: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/samples/org.eclipse.swt.examples/doc-html/swt_manual_setup.html

downloaded the plugin .zip sdk here: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6.2-201102101200/index.php#ExamplePlugins under "Example plug-ins"

and tried to create a new project from the existing jar file org.eclipse.swt.examples.paint.source_3.1.100.v3659b.jar

Since jars are actually zip files, I could import two source files:
PaintPlugin.java and PaintView.java

But they are not complete!
The example is far more elaborated than the few lines described in these two files, just to make it clear: running the SWT plugin "paint" allows me to draw rectangles, circles, rounded-corners rectangles, change colors, etc... the lines in the abovementioned files instead allows me nothing!! The view won't even show

What am I missing? Can someone help making this clear or pointing me towards a simple/explanatory guide?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install that jar correctly? (as by copying it to the dropins folder etc)

If nothing works out, check out the plugins directly from CVS. They are available here: http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.examples/

[Update]
Eclipse moved to Git from CVS. Find the samples in Git: http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.examples

Comment: I'll check it out as soon as possible